# Como fazer o select voltar para o estado inicial após o "deselect"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

Como fazer para que, quando eu deselecionar um select option específico, ele voltar ao "estado inicial"?

Aqui está uma simulação do meu problema: https://jsfiddle.net/andrealbson/o1xs3m8x/

Answer (score 0):

Veja se é isso que você quer:

```html
<select class="selectpicker" id="funcao">
    <option title="Opção 1">Líder</option>
    <option title="Opção 2">Para Conhecimentor</option>
    <option title="Opção 3">Participante</option>
 </select>
```

[Fonte](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/)

Comment: @Fraga, se você observar o meu exemplo, depois que eu seleciono o option com o value= "1", verá que ele desabilita essas opções nos outros selects, porém se caso o usuário desmarcar esse option, os selects (que tiveram suas option desabilitadas) não conseguem voltar ao "normal", ou seja, reabilitá-las. Entendeu? Eu precisaria que o select voltasse ao seu "estado inicial"...

Comment: E o "estado inicial" seria?

Comment: O "estado inicial" se refere à ele mostrar novamente o option que foi "ocultado" nos demais selects. Na simulação do problema que eu postei, quando é selecionado a opção "Líder", ele remove/oculta essa opção nos outros selects. Mas caso eu desmarque a opção "Líder", os outros selects permanecem com esse option ocultado...
observe o exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/andrealbson/o1xs3m8x/

Answer (score -1):

Se eu entendi, no seu caso você tem que percorrer todos os **options** e desmarcar um a um. Depois só marque o selecionado. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: isso mesmo, mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso..